Reason: Task ':app:extractReleaseNativeSymbolTables' uses this output of task ':app:switchToRelease' without declaring an explicit implicit dependency
android {
namespace = "com.example.app"
compileSdkVersion 35
ndkVersion '28.0.12433566'
//    defaultPublishConfig "debug"
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
    buildConfig true
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pgn.app"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 35
    versionCode 16
    versionName "1.0.16"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

signingConfigs {
    debug {
    }
    release {
        storeFile file('rwar_keystore.jks')
    }
}

buildTypes {

    getByName("release") {
        multiDexKeepProguard = file('multidex-config.pro')
    }

    release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable false
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
    }
    uat {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
task switchToDebug(type: Copy) {
    from "src/development"
    include "google-services.json"
    into "."
}

task switchToRelease(type: Copy) {
    from "src/production"
    include "google-services.json"
    into "."
}

afterEvaluate {
    project.tasks.findByName('processDebugGoogleServices')?.dependsOn switchToRelease
    project.tasks.findByName('processReleaseGoogleServices')?.dependsOn switchToRelease

}
}


Possible solutions:


Declare task ':app:switchToRelease' as an input of ':app:extractReleaseNativeSymbolTables'.

Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:switchToRelease' from ':app:extractReleaseNativeSymbolTables' using Task#dependsOn.

Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:switchToRelease' from ':app:extractReleaseNativeSymbolTables' using Task#mustRunAfter.


But this shows more errors, I have tried the solution mentioned by Android studio but it doesn't seem to work
Reason: Task ':app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols' uses this output of task ':app:switchToRelease' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
Reason: Task ':app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs' uses this output of task ':app:switchToRelease' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
